# Magento - filter product collection by multiple SKU's

Tags: magento

I know it's possible to filter a collection by one SKU, as below:

```
$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('SKU', array('like'=>array('my-sku')));
$_testproductCollection->load();
```

But is there some way to add a list of SKU's, like the following (which doesn't work):

```
->addAttributeToFilter('SKU', array('like'=>array('my-sku1, my-sku2, my-sku3')))
```

Comment: Actually, think I'll just use entity_id instead, as that seems to work, but would still be interested in this as well if anyone does have an answer.

Answer (score 22):

I haven't tested this, but I believe something like this should work:

```
->addAttributeToFilter( 'sku', array( 'in' => array( 'my-sku1', 'my-sku2', 'my-sku3' ) ) )
```

Comment: Tried like this and the way I listed above but no joy. Can't see why it doesn't work though.

Comment: What version of Magento?  I just tested this on Enterprise 1.9.1.1 and it worked.  $_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter( 'SKU', array( 'in' => array( 'sku1', 'sku2', 'sku3' ) ) );
$_testproductCollection->load();

Comment: Confirmed Matt Humphrey's comment.  Lowercase 'sku' did the trick for me.

Answer (score 11):

For future adventurers.

```
$productSkuString = 'PROD001, PROD002, PROD003';
$productIds = explode(', ', $productSkuString);

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // <- careful with this
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'sku', array('in' => $productIds)
    )
    ->load();

// usage
foreach($products as $prod) {
    echo $prod->getName();
}
```

Tested in 1.7.0.2 and 1.8.1.0.

Comment: works great in 1.9.3  wouldn't hurt to add a `trim` to `$productIds = explode(', ', trim($productSkuString));`

Answer (score 1):

You need split 'addAttributeToFilter' or split second params in this functionly
example:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
array(
    array('attribute'=>'sku','like'=>"%$sku%"),
    array('attribute'=>'sku','like'=>"%$sku%")
));
```

Comment: I try it in magento 1.7.0.2 and it's not working. "Cannot determine the field name."